# Using SignalR (Core) periodically causes thread hang

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

We're having an issue in production that is really difficult to diagnose. The symptom is, when using SignalR one or more threads on the server periodically hangs. When it happens the other threads seem to continue merrily, unless one of them also experience this problem.

No error is logged, but creating a dump reveals the threads experiencing an ObjectDisposedException at:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SafeCloseSocket.GetOrAllocateThreadPoolBoundHandle(Boolean) 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.GetOrAllocateThreadPoolBoundHandleSlow() 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.DoOperationSendSingleBuffer(System.Net.Sockets.SafeCloseSocket) 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendAsync(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)
```

If we disable SignalR on the client side, there is no problem.

We've scaled back the websocket functionality to a point where we only create an empty hub, and the problem still persists.

We initialize SignalR with:

```cs
services.AddSignalR();

app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
   routes.MapHub<LiveHub>("/live");
});
```

The contents of LiveHub.cs is:

```cs
 public class LiveHub : Hub<ILiveHub>
    {
        public Task Ping()
        {
            return Clients.Caller.SendMessage("pong");
        }
    }
```

We are running on AWS behind an Application Loadbalancer, but only on one server currently.

Anyone else have had this problem?

Comment: Is there any error log beside that ? And another question is your code successfully run the local ?

Comment: No, we can't see any errors besides that. Yes, the code runs fine locally, but of course not under the same load.